# checkbox label overlaps in 1024 x 768 resolution

Tags: html, css

My JSP code is

```
<h:field
  path="configuredChannels" 
  required="true" 
  code="admin.menu.channels">
    <div class="row-fluid" 
      data-channel-checkboxes="#">
        <form:checkboxes 
          element="div class='span1 checkbox'" 
          items="${channels}" 
          path="configuredChannels" />
    </div>
</h:field>
```

However the checkbox items works fine on all other resolutions but the item channel value facebook just overlaps with the next checkbox only on 1024 X 768.

here is the jpeg image.
[image]

Here is the resulting client code in HTML

```
          <div class="controls">
                <div class="row-fluid" data-channel-checkboxes="#">
 <div class='span1 checkbox'>
<input id="configuredChannels1" name="configuredChannels" type="checkbox" value="SMS"/><label for="configuredChannels1">SMS</label>
</div class='span1 checkbox'>
<div class='span1 checkbox'>
<input id="configuredChannels2" name="configuredChannels" type="checkbox" value="Voice"/><label for="configuredChannels2">Voice</label></div class='span1 checkbox'>
<div class='span1 checkbox'><input id="configuredChannels3" name="configuredChannels" type="checkbox" value="Facebook"/><label for="configuredChannels3">Facebook</label></div class='span1 checkbox'>
<div class='span1 checkbox'><input id="configuredChannels4" name="configuredChannels" type="checkbox" value="Twitter"/><label for="configuredChannels4">Twitter</label>
</div class='span1 checkbox'><input type="hidden" name="_configuredChannels" value="on"/></div>
<span class="help-inline">
                    </span>
           </div>
       </div>
```

Latest Images
[image]

Comment: Could you post your resulting client code that is relevant to the checkbox items (and the `div`s containing them)? I think it will help in getting accurate responses.

Comment: I have added client code

Comment: Can you also post the related CSS code too? I think the problem may lie in the CSS code more than anything. I suspect `.span1` or `.checkbox` styles are setting their width explicitly or something similar. Depending on the code, using a `min-width` instead may correct that.

Comment: Looks like your checkboxes are a fixed width (and not wide enough for 'facebook'). Please post the CSS.

Comment: here is the checkbox css
.radio, .checkbox {
min-height: 18px;
padding-left: 18px;
}

The issue i found lies in the following code 
.row-fluid [class*=span] {
display: block;
width: 100%;
min-height: 30px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
float: left;
margin-left: 3.4482758620689653%;
}
when I remove margin-left , it gets displayed properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a fluid row grid and give the checkboxes a fluid span width:

```
<div class="row-fluid" data-channel-checkboxes="#">
 <div class='span1 checkbox'>
```

This means that the `row-fluid` is always 100% of the width of it's container (whatever that may be in the context of your HTML, and the checkbox divs have the `span1` class, which is always 6.382978723404255% of the row-fluid width. (This is defined in Twitter Bootstrap)

When you resize the window the 100% of the row-fluid becomes smaller, and at a certain point it hits the mark where ~6.38% of that is not enough to fit the entire contents of the checkbox.

There is no simple solution for this while maintaining this fluid grid, it's doing exactly what it's supposed to do but you probably didn't intend this. A better solution would probably be to not give the checkboxes a defined width just let them use all the width they need.

Try removing `span1` from the checkbox divs, and add this CSS:

```
.checkbox {
  float: left;
}
```

This means that they will not have the evenly distributed width they used to have, but instead once there is not enough room to show all of them on one line the checkboxes will continue on a new line.

*addition*

You're setting classes on the closing tag of a div. That is completely useless. Classes (and all other attributes) should only be set on the opening tag (`<div>`), never on `</div>`

Comment: I have removed span1 and added the css code given. and I have posted the images how it looks . 
The channels names now come below the textboxes

Comment: An image isn't going to help, we can't debug that. Put it in a http://jsfiddle.net